# In a Python bot, how to run a function only once a day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I have a Python bot running PRAW for Reddit. It is open source and thus users could schedule this bot to run at any frequency (e.g. using `cron`). It could run every 10 minutes, or every 6 hours.

I have a specific function (let's call it `check_logs`) in this bot that should not run every execution of this bot, but rather only once a day. The bot does not have a database.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Python without external databases/files?

Comment: If the script stops and starts every once in a while (so cant save time in variable) and there is no permanent parent program/script that calls it that can hold a variable with the last time the script executed, then you'd want to write a file imo. Needn't be complicated just throw the current unix time in there. 

It also depends on how accurate you want "once a day" to be? precisely every 24.0000.. hours or just "close enough"?

Question is confusing, too detail-light. I dont understand why you cant schedule the function to run much like those others do? Or are those not related.

Comment: Once a day is fine, or "end of day". It doesn't have to be 24 hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's better (and easier) to use the external database or file. But, if you absolutely need it you could also:

1. Modify the script itself, e.g. store the date of the last run in commented out last line of the script.
2. Store the date of the last update on the web, for example, in your case it could be a Reddit post or google doc or draft email or a site like Pastebin, etc.
3. Change the "modified date" of the script itself and use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `cron` you can run it with [command line arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

And define in cron eg. `python3 main.py daily` for the daily run that you need and `python3 main.py frequent` for the other version.

I'm doing it that way and it worked optimally by now.